# Current customer cart prices does not update after catalog price rules are inactive

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

Here's the problem:

- Logged in customer adds a product the cart that is on sale based on catalog price rules.
- The price rule goes inactive.
- Customer comes back the next day and the price in their cart is still the sale price!

This is a huge issue! I found that if the customer adds a product currently not on sale, when the promotion kicks in, their cart price correctly updates to the new sale price. Then when it goes inactive again, it also updates. This issue only seems to happen if when adding the product to the cart, the promotion is active on the product.

Yes, I've reindexed all and Save and Applied the promotion rule. Hope somebody knows a fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an checkout_cart_product_add_after observer that was setting the custom and original_custom price fields in the sales_flat_quote_item table if the product is on sale, causing the price of that product to not change when the sale ends!

Comment: Shaquille, how did you fix the problem?  I'm not versed on coding that well, but this is a big issue.

Comment: This issue shouldn't exist by default. It's because a co-worker added an Observer which said "After a customer adds a product to their cart, if it is on sale, populate the field **custom_price** in the table **sales_flat_quote_item** with $x". (This was in order to support price rules on custom option).

Because the custom_price field is populated, the quoted price will never update when the product price changes (custom_price overrides product price). I've made a fix for this by changing the observed event and a few other things, which I won't get into unless somebody asks.